# ARMSim out of valid memory range

Tags: assembly, arm

Hey I'm really new to ARM and our prof is having us write(finish) a simple program dealing with adding numbers and outputting a Base-16 answer. Whenever I try to test it in ARMSim I am getting the "PC out of valid memory range, address 00000008." I do not know if it I have just not written enough code or if it is something wrong with the pre-written code as this is basically my first assembly program I've worked with. I pretty much have only written one line, adding the 2 numbers and storing them, so the former could be true.

```
        .equ SWI_Exit, 0x11             @ exit gracefully
        .equ SWI_Close, 0x68            @ close file
        .equ SWI_Open, 0x66             @ open file
        .equ SWI_ReadINT, 0x6c          @ read integer from fd in R0 -> R0
        .equ SWI_WriteINT, 0x6b         @ write integer in R1 to fd in R0
        .equ SWI_WriteS, 0x69           @ write string to stdout

        .text                       
        .global _start             
_start:                                 @ The simulator will look for "_start".
        ldr     r0, =filename           @ R0 is the address of the file
        mov     r1, #0                  @ R1 = 0 so we open it "read only"
        swi     SWI_Open                @ Do the software interrupt to open the file
        bcs     file_not_found          @ "Branch if carry set" if it did not work.
        ldr     r1, =file_handle        @ Otherwise save the file handle for reading.
        str     r0, [r1]                @ It is stored at "file_handle"

        @ Here's the top of the "loop" in terms of reading the numbers
        @ and seeing if they are not both zero. We'll put the first number
        @ in R6 and the second in R7 (arbitrary choices).
        
loop:   ldr     r1, =file_handle        @ Load the file handle 
        ldr     r0, [r1]                @ It goes into R0
        swi     SWI_ReadINT             @ Ask the operating system to read one number.
        mov     r6, r0                  @ Let's put the first number in R6 (just because)
        
        ldr     r1, =file_handle        @ Load the file handle again
        ldr     r0, [r1]
        swi     SWI_ReadINT
        mov     r7, r0                  @ Let's put the second number in R7

        @ Here you will need to test to see if both numbers are zero,
        @ within the range in the assignment, and so on.
        @ If they are, then continue, else branch down to where
        @ the error prints out.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
@ Here's where you come in!
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    


        @ Put your answer into R1 so that we can print it
        mov     r0, #1                  @ stdout
        add     r1, r6 ,r7              @ adds r6 and r7 and stores answer in r1 (only line written by me) 
        swi     SWI_WriteINT
        ldr     r1, =newline
        swi     SWI_WriteS                              
        b       loop                    @ Next set of numbers please.

bad_int:mov     r0, #1                  @ Stdout
        ldr     r1, =bad_string         @ Write the bad data string
        swi     SWI_WriteS
        b       loop
        
end_of_file:
        ldr     r0, =file_handle
        ldr     r0, [r0]
        swi     SWI_Close
        swi     SWI_Exit

file_not_found:                     
        mov     r0, #1                  @ In the case where we could
        ldr     r1, =in_file_error      @ not open the file, of course
        swi     SWI_WriteS              @ there is no need to close it.
        swi     SWI_Exit                @ So bail out.

@ ============================================================
@ Data
@ ============================================================
        
        .data

        @ Any "word" must be aligned on four bytes
        .align  4
file_handle:    .word 0x00

        @ Strings can be aligned anywhere.
filename:       .asciz  "CARRY.TXT"
in_file_error:  .asciz  "No such file???\n"
bad_string:     .asciz  "The file contains invalid data!\n"
newline:        .asciz  "\n"
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to try to run it in the simulator?  Are you able to run any other programs that way?

Comment: @NateEldredge Theres basically just a "run" button that I am pressing. There is a console view that outputs the error as well as run status and such. Then you have another view that has the stdout/stdin/stderr. Nothing shows in this view becuase I am assuming I do not have enough code or becuase of the memory error. I have not tried to run anything else in it though

Comment: @NateEldredge It seems like the memory error is originating at r15, `r15 (pc) : 00000008` at or before the line   `swi     SWI_Open                @ Do the software interrupt to open the file` but I still am not sure why that is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you haven't enabled the swi plugin. Go to file>preferences>plugins and then tick SWIInstructions.